# How can I upload to S3 with CLI using server side encryption with customer provided key

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am unable to upload an S3 object into an S3 bucket.  I have used the command below:

> aws s3api put-object --bucket=opsops --key=Cloudformation_upload.csv --body=Cloudformation.csv --sse-customer-algorithm=AES256 --sse-customer-key=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MGFiY2Rl --customer-key-md5=NTgwMWMzMzJiNGU1YmE5YzBhMjk3ZDYwYmI1MWNjNzI="

But when I upload the object gives this error:

Note:Customer-key and customer-key-MD5 values are encoded with 64bits value.Please help me to resolve this.

> A client error (InvalidArgument) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was provided

Comment: The command I executed for this...

Command is "aws s3api put-object 
--bucket=opsops 
--key=Cloudformation_upload.csv 
--body=Cloudformation.csv 
--sse-customer-algorithm=AES256 
--sse-customer-key=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MGFiY2Rl
--customer-key-md5=NTgwMWMzMzJiNGU1YmE5YzBhMjk3ZDYwYmI1MWNjNzI="

Answer (score 1):

Store your key as a binary file (not hex or base64 encoded) and use `fileb://` on the command line.  The CLI will automatically calculate the correct MD5.

In your example, you're using a base-64 encoded MD5 hash but MD5 produces only 16 bytes.  For AES256 your key should be exactly 32 bytes in length.  Hashing a passphrase with SHA256 will produce a key of the correct size.

Example:

```
echo -n 1234567890abcde | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary > sse.key
aws s3api put-object \
    --bucket=opsops \
    --key=Cloudformation_upload.csv \
    --body=Cloudformation.csv \
    --sse-customer-algorithm=AES256 \
    --sse-customer-key=fileb://sse.key
```

Comment: I executed this given command and checked in the S3 bucket after uploading this object(Cloudformation_upload.csv).But it is not encrypted.

Comment: When using a customer key, the console may not show it as encrypted in the properties tab under details.  Try downloading the file from the console.  If it's encrypted, it will fail with an HTTP 400 status code and the message "The object was stored using a form of Server Side Encryption. The correct parameters must be provided to retrieve the object."

Comment: To correctly download the file, you'll need to call the get-object api with the same customer key.